# How to hook in an ongoing transition without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Is there a way to do something when a transition - let's say - finished for 60%? An API easy as transition-end-listener but just for any amount of transition-progress.

Pseudocode:

```
node.addEventListener('transitionat', () => alert('foo'), {progress: 60})
```

When a transition-duration is set to 1s, the app would execute `alert('foo')` after 600 ms.

What's the currently best possible solution to achieve this?

<sub>Note: using setTimeout is not an option</sub>

---

Currently *my* best solution/hack is to just use a "unused" transition-property:

```js
let callBackStamp = 0;
let transitionStamp = 0;

mainz.addEventListener('transitionend', event => {
  if (event.propertyName !== 'transform') {
    callBackStamp = Date.now();
    console.log('simulate callback at ', callBackStamp);
  } else {
    transitionStamp = Date.now();
    console.log('finished with delay ', transitionStamp - callBackStamp);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.something {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  transition-property: transform, background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s, 600ms;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}

div.something:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  transform: translate(10px, 5px);
  z-index: 2;
}

div.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainz" class="square something">Hover plz</div>
```

But this is of course quite dirty and also it's hard to find a property which is available for transition, manipulatable so that it is triggering the transition but in a way not recognisable by the user and also not needed productively for the UI (you can't just use background-color if you actually *have* a background-color configured/maintained).